# Does this refer to the original or sale price? W: "How much were they?" M: "70 dollars. I got them on sale. They were 30% off."

Tags: meaning, numbers

> W: I like your sports shoes very much. How much were they?
> M: 70 dollars. I got them on sale. They were 30% off.

> What was the original price of the new shoes?
> A. 120 dollars. B. 70 dollars. C. 100 dollars D. 91 dollars

Interpretation one: the original price was $70, but I bought them for 30% off.
Interpretation two:  I bought them for $70, which is 30 percentage off the original price.

I think the second one is more likely, but is the first one totally impossible？

Comment: How much were they means what did you pay, not originally. "They were $70 on sale, 30% off." The original price was $100.

Comment: Technically ambiguous, but normally understood to mean you *paid* $70. On the other hand, if the second line had been "70 dollars, **but** I got them on sale" the original price would have been the $70.

Comment: Your 'interpretation two' should read "I bought _them_ for $70, which is 30% _less than_ the original price".

Comment: @Peter - not ambiguous. 'How much' something 'is' always refers to the price you need to pay, the actual selling price. They were $70.

Comment: @KateBunting  Can I also say "..., which is 30% **off** of the original price?"

Comment: It is ambiguous. If someone asks the price of something, it's reasonable to give the standard price or the price they would have to pay. it doesn't necessarily denote the amount the speaker paid. Especially if you got some special or non-standard discount. Certainly you could say "How much were the shoes?" "$70. But I used my staff discount so they were only $35."

Comment: @Stuart - I see it the other way around. How much **were** they? They **were** $35, but they **would have been** $70 if I didn't have staff discount.

Comment: Well, I would prefer "30% off the original price" (for _off of_, see [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111305/the-meaning-of-off-of).

Comment: Is this an English language quiz or a math quiz?

Comment: Even if you think it *could* possibly be 30% off of $70, that answer ($49) is not among the options.

Comment: "How much were they?" "70."  Clearly the price paid was 70.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The options are for the original price. $49 is 30% off an original $70.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Not clear at all.  "They were $70, but today they're on sale for $49." is a perfectly correct use of the past tense.  But so is "Sticker price is $100, but they were $70 when I bought them."

Comment: @BenVoigt I would interpret "How much were they?" to mean "What was the price at the time you bought them?", not "What was the price at some prior time?".  (I suppose it _could_ mean that in a different context...)

Comment: @JohnGordon: And it could mean that in this context.  I'm not saying your interpretation is invalid.  It's perfectly valid.  But not unambiguous.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a maths question.

Answer (score 18):

There's clear context here - the question is preceded by the statement "*I like **your** shoes*". The pronoun 'they' in the question must refer to that particular pair, because 'they' always refers to things previously mentioned. Secondly, the past tense verb, 'were', is used in the question before the respondent mentions the sale, so there is no reason to think that the question is looking for the pre-sale price. They want to know how much the person paid for that particular pair.

The same logic has to be applied to the answer - the respondent gives the asker exactly what they want, so $70 is the price they paid. In an entirely separate sentence, they mention that was a sale price. Then, in a third separate sentence, they tell them how much the discount was. So, the original price of the shoes was $100, and $70 was paid in the sale.

Comment: I disagree that this is clear from the language.  I'd tend to lean toward your interpretation, but I can easily see someone meaning that the regular price was $70, but they got the shoes at 30% off *from that*.  However, it is clear from the *math* context, because $49 is not one of the options available.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry you don't follow the logic, but yes you are right about the maths; it just isn't right to answer English language questions with maths.

Comment: Oh no, I *follow* the logic just fine.  I simply don't accept it.  You're reading much more into the specific word choices than is reliable for a casual conversation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Why would you be looking for $49 as an answer choice? The question is the *original price*. So in the scenario you "can easily see", the answer would be (B) $70.

Comment: This is not a valid argument. You can tell this, because replacing "and" with "but" doesn't _specifically_ counter anything in this argument ... but changes the primary interpretation of the sentence (it's still ambiguous but it now leans in the other direction).

Comment: John Bollinger is right that it's ambiguous. It *should* mean what you said it means, but that assumes the three sentences were one coherent thought. If this was said in a casual conversation, it might not have been. "70 dollars. [oh! I just remembered] I got them on sale. They were 30% off. [I only paid 49 for them.]"

Comment: I don't really understand the logic that "there is no reason to think that the question is looking for the pre-sale price" - there's also not much reason to think it's asking about the *post*-sale price, as the asker didn't even know there *was* a sale when they asked. I find both interpretations rather plausible, as the shoes certainly were $100 before they went on sale. They were $100, then they were $70, and it's not clear which point in time is being asked (or answered) about.

Comment: People talk like this all the time. They say how much they paid and the amount without mentioning the original price.

Comment: It is LIKELY that $70 is the price paid, and that that price was 30% off. However it is completely impossible to know for sure, because A) English does not always follow rules of logic and B) English speakers do not always follow the rules of English. In casual spoken conversation, people often start and stop, interrupt themselves, jump around, and otherwise render ambiguous statements. The only way you could ever know for sure would be to ask the person who said it to clarify.

Comment: @barbecue These arguments are like trying to prove that 2+2=5. No native speaker with half a brain would make a statement as misleading as you suggest. Why would you want to mislead English learners reading this? If something is true 99% of the time, that's what you teach, not the 1% outcome.

Comment: @Astralbee Having been a native speaker for more than 60 years, and having lived my entire life in the US among native speakers, I can assure you you are absolutely wrong. There is nothing "misleading" about such a statement, it's simply ambiguous. And ambiguity in conversational English is common.  Why would YOU want to mislead English learners by pretending that there's a hard-and-fast rule they can rely on when the reality is they cannot know for sure without asking for clarification? Claiming that there is a clear rule about this is complete BS.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Astralbee's logic is crystal clear, and 100% correct.  This is a simple math word problem: `M` *paid* $70 for the shoes.  They were 30% off.  That means $70 is 30% less than the full price.

Comment: @astralbee This is not a word problem in a math textbook, it's two people having a chat. You're the one making the extraordinary claim that there can be no other interpretation of the statements. All I said was you were LIKELY right, but POSSIBLY something else was intended. There's ambiguity. You don't see it. That's your limitation. \

Comment: This is a good example of why creating word problems for math textbooks should be left to professionals.

Comment: @RonJohn, although I agree that $100 is the expected answer to the math problem, the amount of concurrence with my previous comments shows that a non-trivial proportion of active, privileged users of this site find that Astralbee's logic does not satisfactorily analyze the language of the sentence under consideration.  That in itself seems to establish the point that the sentence is indeed ambiguous, but if you or others nevertheless insist otherwise then so be it.  I hope that expressing your disagreement made you feel better.

Comment: @barbecue "This is not a word problem in a math textbook, it's two people having a chat." The whole point of _word_ problems is situations like this.

Comment: @Ronjohn Designing good test questions is hard, and even professional psychometricians sometimes get it wrong. Written representations of spoken language are especially hard to get right, because there is no way to represent the slight pauses, shifts in tone, facial expressions, and other cues that might help resolve the ambiguity. This question IS ambiguous. The ambiguity is whether the $70 is the price actually paid or the price before discount. It could be improved by add the words "I paid" in front of the 70 to eliminate that ambiguity.

Comment: @barbecue “How much is that doggie in the window?”  “It was $325.”  That’s how much it cost when you bought it, whether on not $325 is full price, 30% off of full price , 50% off or 90% off of full price.

Comment: @ronjohn Your attempt to prove there's no ambiguity is ambiguous. “How much is that doggie in the window?” That's asking what the price of the dog is (present tense.)  “It was $325” (past tense.) That could mean someone paid $325 in the past, but it also could mean nobody paid anything, and the price of the dog used to be $325, with the current price unknown. Nothing in either of those two statements indicates anyone has actually bought the dog. Your conclusion that someone did buy it and did pay that price is completely unjustified.  As I said, writing good unambiguous questions is hard.

Comment: @barbecue your argument is so insane, I think you’re trolling.

Answer (score 12):

Both interpretations are possible. Normally I'd assume the person meant that he paid $70, i.e. that that is the price after getting 30% off, so that the original price was $100.

As a math question, the only plausible interpretation is that $70 is the price after the discount. If it was the original price, than the question is trivial. "The original price was $70. What was the original price?" Well, duh. So I'd interpret the question to mean that the sale price is $70. Well, I suppose it could be intended to be a trick question. But probably not.

Comment: I can't agree with the statement that both interpretations are possible at all. You'd have to strip away all context beyond a simple question and an answer, as well as completely change the construction and punctuation of the answer in order to create the ambiguity needed for any other interpretation. The only astute observation here is that this is a maths question. Seems to me the OP got it wrong and they are turning to English grammar in order to prove that 2+2=5.

Comment: I have to agree with @Astralbee here. A native speaker, presenting the alternative interpretation, would say something line "$70, but they were 30% off so I only paid $49."

Comment: @Astralbee Well, I think the interpretation that $70 was the original price is POSSIBLE. If I had this conversation with someone and I really cared, I'd ask, "Do you mean the original price was $70 or that the sale price was $70?" But if that interpretation would never occur to you, okay fine, not worth arguing about.

Comment: Was this a math question, or a multiple-choice English comprehension question?  Either way 100$ is the most likely interpretation for the pre-sale price, if we assume the speaker is precise and careful in their use of language.

Comment: This is utterly wrong.  "W: How much were they?"  "M: 70 dollars."  **That's how much you paid for them.**  Nobody says "I paid the full price" when you buy something on sale.  You say you paid what you actually paid.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've seen some pretty bad examples of supposedly correct English in non-native text books, exams, etc.  Interpretation Two is the correct answer for a native speaker who can do *basic* word problems.

Comment: @RonJohn It would certainly be inaccurate for someone to reply to, "How much did you pay for that?" by saying, "$100", when actually he got it on sale for $100. But it would not be at all inaccurate or strange to say, "The regular price was $100 but I got it on sale for 30% off." Given that, for someone to abbreviate by saying, "$100. I got it on sale for 30% off" would not be a startling thing for someone to say. At which point it is ambiguous: did he mean that the base price is $100 or the sale price was $100?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly say, "It would be more clear if people always worded it this way." But they don't necessarily. Language is full of ambiguous statements, often because of such inconsistencies.

Comment: ***for someone to abbreviate** by saying, "$100. I got it on sale for 30% off" would not be a startling thing for someone to say.*  That's patently absurd.  You must be a federal bureaucrat, for whom a 4% budget increase is considered a budget cut.

Comment: @RonJohn Well, I disagree, I think that's a very plausible thing for a person to say. Ambiguous and confusing, but people say ambiguous and confusing things all the time. But I'll leave it there. We disagree, neither of us is likely to convince the other, and odds are we're not close enough to resolve it with a friendly fight to the death. Feel free to get the last word.

Comment: @ronjohn And I am most certainly NOT a government bureaucrat and never have been, and I am deeply offended by this insult!